# How can I shorten my customized PS1 prompt?

Tags: bash, prompt

I currently have my prompt as

```
durrantm@Castle2012-Ubuntu-laptop01:~/Dropnot/webs/rails_apps/linker (master)
$
```

which I really like as it shows my username, machine, directory and git branch!

How can I shorten the machine part though?

i.e. how could In have it be:

```
durrantm@Castle...:~/Dropnot/webs/rails_apps/linker (master)
$
```

I tried various combination of h:0:6 but had no luck getting a correct syntax that would work.

My .bashrc uses this:

```
function parse_git_branch () {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$(parse_git_branch)\n\$ '
```

Comment: Why not shorten the hostname itself? from `Castle2012-Ubuntu-laptop01` to be `castle2012`, for example.

Comment: That's too easy ;)  Yes that worked well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Improving [terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114209/28235), you don't even need to invoke those two processes (`hostname` and `cut`). Just use `bash`'s string manipulation:

```
PS1="\[\033[01;32m\]\u@${HOSTNAME:0:10}\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$(parse_git_branch)\n\$ "
```

Comment: If the `-` is to be the delimiter, the much better solution is `${HOSTNAME%%-*}`.

Answer (score 3):

I have to agree with @aularon that it would make more sense to shorten your hostname, that's a ridiculously long name. However, you can also get what you want by parsing it:

```
## For example, take the first 10 chars of hostname
name=$(hostname | cut -c -10);

## Now use $name in your PS1 instead of \h
PS1="\[\033[01;32m\]\u@$name\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$(parse_git_branch)\n\$ "
```

That should produce a prompt like:

```
durrantm@Castle2012:~/Dropnot/webs/rails_apps/linker (master)
```

Comment: +1 I'm going with the hostname change but this info is useful and may help others.